# How to Reset a Dell EqualLogic PS6100 Without Password or Serial Access

Tags: serial, dell-equallogic, reset

I have before me a Dell EqualLogic PS6100 with two Type 11 (green) controllers. I have been tasked with refurbishing the unit ready for resale for an IT  waste recycling firm. My boss is one of those wonderful people who gives you something to work on without telling you what's happening; it took me two weeks to find out why we had it in the first place. The firm has not been given any of the configuration details about the controllers (no passwords, no management port IP address/subnet) and it appears the serial ports have been disabled as well.

Is there any way to perform a hardware factory reset without requiring console/management interface? I have so far been unable to find anything in the documentation or the ol' Gargler.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "appears the serial ports have been disabled" ? You need access via console connection in order to perform any reset. Also, did you try using the default grpadmin passwords ?

Comment: I am getting no output from the console during power up (9600baud, no init, 8bit); no power status, no welcome message, no prompts.

Comment: I am connected to the "active" controller, by the way :)

Comment: The defaults serial settings are: 9600 baud, no parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no flow control. But previous admins could of changed the baud rate, so you should test with higher ones like 115200.

Comment: After trying all possible setting combinations it turns out that ALL of my serial adapters and cables were faulty. After buying a new USB-Serial adapter and Null Modem cable, I was able to get output from the management port :facepalm: Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: Given that, I also found during my 15+ years of work with such things an unusual amount of not working serial cables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a serial cable and follow this guide :

https://dfwlpiki.dfwlp.com/index.php/Breaking_Into_and_Resetting_an_Equallogic.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/512452)